# weird TS import problems

Tags: typescript

I have a npm module that I have used for a number of my Typescript projects called `common-types` (repo: https://github.com/lifegadget/common-types). Recently added an enum for my work with Firebase projects called `FirebaseEvent` which is defined as:

```
export enum FirebaseEvent {
  value = 'value',
  child_added = 'child_added',
  child_moved = 'child_moved',
  child_removed = 'child_removed',
  child_changed = 'child_changed'
};
```

The problem I'm having is that when I try and import that enum with the following expression:

```
import { FirebaseEvent } from 'common-types';
```

I get the following error:

[image]

For reference sake, line 5 of the common-types file is:

```
 export interface IDictionary<T = any> {
   [key: string]: T;
 }
```

And I strongly suspect that error message is a red-herring as if I import any of the following it works without error:

```
import { IDictionary } from 'common-types';
import { IDictionary, datetime } from 'common-types';
```

And yet any import that includes `FirebaseEvent` -- such as below -- fails with the same error message as above:

```
import { IDictionary, FirebaseEvent } from 'common-types';
```

Answer (score 1):

I won't claim to know why this works, nor will I claim that I came up with the idea, but apparently, adding the export of an empty class to your common-types.ts file will enable you to export your enum without getting any errors.

The exact issue you are facing with your enum is [discussed here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Angular2/comments/4dmcya/how_to_export_an_enum_similar_to_a_class_and/). Look at the comments by users mtz2537 and bits__and_bytes.

Also visit the [plunk they created](http://plnkr.co/edit/F381BldRSp3JCzkjJbEa) to illustrate that adding the empty class solves the issue. The class they added is simply:

```
export class env {

}
```

Open the dev tools console, try removing/adding this empty class that is exported from the environment.ts file, and you'll see that their hack works. Oddly enough, you don't even have to import this class anywhere. As long as the .ts file that contains your enum also exports an empty class, you shouldn't see any errors.

Comment: i now get the syntax error on my empty class: `export class __workaround__ {}​​`